# Improve Callback API performance

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have a callback method `SMSCallBack` which is called by 3rd party SMS vendor in order to update the status changes. When the number of callbacks are high, there are just too many calls to the database for every callback and it just lags the entire web application. Will simply making the method Async help? Or is there a way to keep the callbacks in an array and only then send it to database? Any pointers to the right direction would be much much appreciated.

```
public IActionResult SMSCallBack(MvSMSStatusCallback statusCallback)
{
    string jsonParam = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(statusCallback);
    return Ok(_commonService.SMSStatusUpd(jsonParam));  <---Database call
}
```

Comment: Making Asyn would help up to an extent. Did you try that? If the load is too large for the server and the database to handle then you will have to look for other approach.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya there is a possibility that number of callbacks may go up to 5k per hour.

Comment: I don't know if your server and database will be able to handle 5k per hour traffic along with other application traffic because I don't know what is the size of your web server, your database server and how well written your code is... so question to your answer depends on lot of factors and analysis. Why don't you try making all controller actions and methods as async and see if you get better outcome than current..

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank You. I am going to try async.